# Datepicker Inside appendTo() not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Datepicker is activated using the jquery onclick as follows.

```
  $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
        });
```

It works inside the single text box. but when create multiple boxes using the `appendTo()` Datepicker inside the new appended textboxes is not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var counter2 =2;
    $("#addButton2").click(function () {

var newTextBoxDiv2 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2' + counter2);
    newTextBoxDiv2.after().html('<input type="text" id="datepicker'+counter2+'" name="datepicker3" class="input" />');

    newTextBoxDiv2.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup2");
    counter2++;
    });
```

Comment: And why would it, the element doesn't exist when you instantiate the datepicker ?

Comment: You have to initialize plugin once element is part of the DOM

Comment: you have to call here `counter2++; //here });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the input into a new variable and then invoke `datepicker`:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var counter2 =2;
    $("#addButton2").click(function () {

        var newTextBoxDiv2 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2' + counter2);
        var datePicker = $("<input/>",{
            type: "text",
            id: "datepicker-" + counter2,
            name: "datepicker" + counter2
        });
        $(datePicker).datepicker();

        newTextBoxDiv2.append(datePicker);
        newTextBoxDiv2.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup2");
        counter2++;

    });
 });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yj3yb/4/

---

**On a side note**

jQuery can create elements for you.  For example, this:

```
var newTextBoxDiv2 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2' + counter2);
```

could be tidied up to:

```
   var newTextBoxDiv2 = $("<div/>").attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2' + counter2);
```